# one dimensional array read names from txt file

Tags: vb.net

I want to make my click procedure read five names on a list called "names.txt" file and store them in a five element one dimensional array and then arrange them in descending order.

What am I missing from this code that is keeping the file from displaying? Nothing shows up in the display.

This is what I tried

```
Dim infile As IO.StreamReader
Dim names(4) As String
Dim filename As String = "names.txt"

'checks if the file exist, else show a messagebox
If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
    infile = IO.File.OpenText(filename) 'opens the file
    names = infile.ReadToEnd.Split()
    Array.Reverse(names)
    namesListBox.Items.AddRange(names)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("The file " & filename & " does not exist")
End If
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: Nothing is displaying because you are doing nothing with `names` once you've read the lines. Unrelated, but you could simply use `IO.File.ReadAllLines()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? it's return value is a string array.
you can use [string.join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the array to a single string.
Try this:

```
Dim FineName As String = "names.txt"
Dim names() As String


If IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
    names = IO.File..ReadAllLines(FileName)
    Array.Reverse(names)
    'a message box to show the array's content:
    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, names))
Else
    MessageBox.Show("The file   does not exist")
End If
```

Comment: This doesn't fully answer OP's question: **"arrage them in descending order what am i missing from this code that is keeping the file from displaying"**